# How to detect no spaces in AND ( | ) capture group, in decimal

Tags: regex

I am working to create an expression entirely in decimal. I want to account for instances where `,` could also be a space, not a space, a space then `,`, or `,` then space. I'm not certain that `\s\S` will work in this situation.

```
118,97,114,105,97,98,108,101
```

Where as I originally worked toward this `118(,|32,|,32|"here is where I would like to capture no space"`

I attempted to break this problem out piece by piece in regex101, but so far I have not had any success.

Comment: Could you give us some examples of what should and should not match?

Comment: @palvarez: Absolutely, as an example I would like each of these to match essentially, with no other exceptions except accounting for no space.  `118,` `118[space] ` `118,[space] `118[space] ,` 

Apologies, still getting used to this forum/platform.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need something like:

```
[\s,]+
```

and replace it with

```
|
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/5q502R/1).

At the end, add the parenthesis at the sides, to get the OR capture group.